# jquery .on() not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have a website in which when I am using

```
$('#in').on('click','#bwSave',function(e){});
```

It is not working.
But when I use

```
$(document).on('click','#bwSave',function(e){});
```

It is working why is it so?

I know the first `.on()` is replacing delegate function in jquery and second `.on()` is replacing `.live()` in jquery.But why the first one is not working?

Comment: does `$('#in')` exist when you run that? .. `$(document)` always exists